# Keys from Dictionary are "disappearing"?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, data-structures

Straightforward solution I was trying to write for LeetCode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/sentence-similarity/

I can't figure out for the life of me why the dictionary I build becomes empty without any operations that explicitly modify it. See the `TEST` comments.

(Apologies if this is something obvious I've missed.)

```
public class Solution {
public bool AreSentencesSimilar(string[] sentence1, string[] sentence2, IList<IList<string>> similarPairs) {
    // TODO: Validation

    int n = sentence1.Length;
    if (sentence2.Length != n)
        return false;

    IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>> synonyms = BuildSynonymLookup(similarPairs);
    // ------------------ TEST! ---------------------
    foreach (var kvp in synonyms)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} -> [{1}]", kvp.Key, string.Join(", ", kvp.Value));
    /*
        The above prints

        great -> [fine, great]
        fine -> [great, fine]
        drama -> [acting, drama]
        acting -> [drama, acting]
        skills -> [talent, skills]
        talent -> [skills, talent]
    */
    // -------------------------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        string word1 = sentence1[i], word2 = sentence2[i];
        // --------------------- TEST! ---------------------------
        if (!synonyms.ContainsKey(word1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("synonyms does not contain '{0}'. It contains [{1}]", word1, string.Join(",", synonyms.Keys));
        }
        // ---- The above prints 'synonyms does not contain great. It contains []'
        if (!synonyms[word1].Contains(word2)) // Unhandled exception. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'great' was not present in the dictionary.
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>> BuildSynonymLookup(in IList<IList<string>> similarPairs)
{
    var synonyms = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>(similarPairs.Count);
    foreach (var pair in similarPairs)
    {
        string w0 = pair[0], w1 = pair[1];
        AddSynonym(synonyms, w0, w1);
        AddSynonym(synonyms, w0, w0);            
        AddSynonym(synonyms, w1, w0);  
        AddSynonym(synonyms, w1, w1);                  
    }
    return synonyms;
}

private static void AddSynonym(in IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>> synonyms, in string word0, in string word1)
{
    if (!synonyms.TryGetValue(word0, out ICollection<string> S))
        synonyms[word0] = S = new HashSet<string>(4);
    S.Add(word1);     
}
```

}

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve] - something we can copy, paste, compile and run without having to work out our own test data.

Comment: @JonSkeet My bad. I will Delete this Question. What I discovered is that I read the requirements wrong and there is a test case where a word from a sentence does not appear in the list of similar pairs (last parameter).

Comment: Right, but you still wouldn't see the output you've claimed - at least, I couldn't reproduce the supposed output (which shows an empty dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is with how you're handling the creation of the HashSet in the AddSynonym method. When you write synonyms[word0] = S = new HashSet(4);, it causes issues because S still points to the original collection. When you modify S, it also modifies the collection inside the dictionary.

To fix this, you should create a temporary variable for the new HashSet and then assign it to both synonyms[word0] and S, something like this :

```
private static void AddSynonym(IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>> synonyms, string word0, string word1)
{
    if (!synonyms.TryGetValue(word0, out ICollection<string> S))
    {
        var newSet = new HashSet<string>(4);
        synonyms[word0] = newSet;
        S = newSet;
    }
    S.Add(word1);
}
```

Comment: "When you modify S, it also modifies the collection inside the dictionary." No, it doesn't, because this branch is only taken when the key *isn't in the dictionary*.